# NodeJS eventloop execution order(process.nextTick and promise)

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, event-loop

Run code below will get:`c,a,d,b`

```
// case 1
const test = async () => {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('a');
  }).then(r => console.log(r));

  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('c');
  });

  console.log(await 'd');

  return 'b';
};
(async () => {
  const r = await test();
  console.log(r);
})();
```

but, if I put process.nextTick below `await 'd'`

```
// case 2
const test = async () => {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('a');
  }).then(r => console.log(r));

  console.log(await 'd');

  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('c');
  });
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('e');
  }).then(r => console.log(r));

  return 'b';
};
(async () => {
  const r = await test();
  console.log(r);
})();
```

I get: `a,d,e,b,c`

why process.nextTick's execution order changes like this?

According to my limitted knowledege, `nextTick` runs before `Promise.resolve()` as shown in `case1`, so I expected to get `a,d,c,e,b` rather than `a,d,e,b,c` in `case2`

Comment: Why exactly is this unexpected? Would you have expected the same order? If you are scheduling the `nextTick` callback later (after an `await`, or inside another async callback), it will also run later.

Comment: What version of Node are you running this in?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your comment. I re-edit the problem to be more specific. I expected to get `a,d,c,e,b` in `case2`, but got `a,d,e,b,c`. `Promise e` runs before `nextTick c` in case2, but in case1, `Promise a` runs after `nextTick c`. That's where i'm confused.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum v9.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

Node.js makes absolutely no guarantees on the order of `process.nextTick` and promise callbacks.

We *may* break this in a patch version since we do not consider it a part of the public API.

You *may not* rely on the internal order of promises and `nextTick`s in order to do things.

---

#### This particular case

This particular case was a "bug" in how we handled promises/callbacks sometimes. It was recently fixed (in a semver-patch) - by getting a nightly version of Node you'll see the expected execution order.

Comment: I really didn't want to link to the actual change since for posterity I think it'd send the long message - but if someone is interested in what we changed https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/18207 . Which we landed as sember-patch.