# Why do callbacks of promises have priority over callbacks of process.nextTick in the microtask queue in event loop?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I am learning how the Node.js event loop works. I understood that the microtask queue always has the highest priority when running asynchronous code in Node.js

The microtask queue consists of the `nextTick` queue and the `Promise` queue. So, within the microtask queue, my understanding is that callbacks in the `nextTick` queue is always processed before the callbacks in the `Promise` queue.

However, when I run the following code:

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log("this is process.nextTick 1"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("this is Promise.resolve 1"));
```

This is the output I always get even if I swap the lines of code. I am running this in a local Node.js (`v20.10.0`) project on a Windows machine.

```
this is Promise.resolve 1
this is process.nextTick 1
```

The result contradicts my understanding of how microtask queue prioritizes it's callbacks. It seems like the `Promise` queue is given priority over the `nextTick` queue.

Can someone please explain what's going on here? When I search online, I see that the `nextTick` queue is given higher priority over the `Promise` queue.

This is the blog post I am referring to learn about event loop in detail.

https://www.builder.io/blog/NodeJS-visualizing-nextTick-and-promise-queues#experiment-2

Screenshot just to show that I am honest just this time XD:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this script is executed as a main task, or is it **itself** executed as a microtask? The difference is significant.

Comment: I am a beginner in Node.js. I don't know what you mean. I just typed the 2 statements in a .js script and ran it through the CLI (node index.js).
How can I tell if the script is executed as a main task or as a microtask?

Comment: Also, I am interested to know the significant difference that you mentioned.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on [v20.10](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq776534855459839). But if you are a beginner, then stay *far* away from using `nextTick`: it is not standard ECMAScript, and you don't need it ... ever.

Comment: Sure, but I just want to understand what's going on here because what I read and understood is not consistent with what I am seeing.

Comment: The expected order is nextTick and then Promise.resolve, but this order is not something you can [rely on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200323/5459839). This behaviour may change. In this instance, I cannot reproduce the output order you get as you can see when you follow the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Interesting. I am just going to internalize the fact that the order of operations with nextTick and Promise cannot be relied on. Thanks for your time @trincot

Comment: Do not attempt to use any knowledge you gain trying to understand it. That knowledge is  counter productive (I'd personally say it's toxic to your ability to write code that works correctly). Asynchronous means unpredictable completion order. End of topic. You can pursue how specific version of Chrome or node work but immediately after you figure it out you need to either forget about what you've learned or remember to never use that knowledge when writing code. Asynchronous means unpredictable completion order - that's the only thing you should know...

Comment: ... If you need the nextTick to happen after the Promise then call it inside the `.then()`. If you need the Promise to happen after the nextTick then create the promise inside the nextTick callback. That's how you control asynchronous flow

Comment: I would advise against using `nextTick` at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [process.nextTick vs queueMicrotask in commonJs and ESM. What is the execution order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518968/process-nexttick-vs-queuemicrotask-in-commonjs-and-esm-what-is-the-execution-or)